# How to change position of Space Markup object during simulation

Tags: java, anylogic

I tried to change position of Space Markup object during simulation with using this code:

```
node.setPos(500.0,0,0);
node.initialize();
```

where `node` is rectangular node from Space Markup. But I get this error

java.lang.RuntimeException: root:
node (RectangularNode) : Markup element is already initialized and cannot be modified. Please use constructor without arguments, perform setup and finally call initialize() function.

I am new in this software, and I want to ask if anyone can help me with this if it is possible to change position of such object? My goal is to change the position of object by a variable which is changing during simulation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this... the space definitions can only be created in the beginning of the simulation and cannot be changed later...

So the question is... why do you want to change the position of a node?

When you are a beginner in AnyLogic, and you want to ask a question, it's better to say what you want to do conceptually, instead of assuming that there is one way of doing it and ask how you do it the way you think it needs to be done.

Comment: I wanted to know because I am interested in reconfiguration manufacturing systems and there the position of the nodes that provide services changes and thus the distance of the material flow as well. I also saw your video in Udemy where you changed the position of the rectangle during the simulation using dynamic value, I wanted to do it with the rectangular node but I already know that it is only possible before the simulation. Thanks for your advice